# Animation and Removing UIButton from SuperView

Tags: ios, swift

I am working with an animation. What I would like to happen is for the UIButton to be removed when the animation is completed, but it always disappears before the animation is completed. Am I missing something?

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!){

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.5, options:[] , animations: {
        background.backgroundColor = Yellow
        }, completion: {finished in button.removeFromSuperview()})
}
```

Comment: Please try changing the duration and delay to higher values like 10.0 and see if the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @ChristianAbella tried that already. Went pretty high and still the same. Plus the performance on the simulator is slower, so 1 sec is more like 5+.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!){

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.5, options:[] , animations: {
        background.backgroundColor = Yellow
        }, completion: {finished in 
            if finished {
                button.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        })
}
```

Use the `finished` flag in the completion block to remove your button

Comment: Still the same. Could it be an issue of the Simulator? Currently do not have a phone to test it on.

Comment: No I don't think its a simulator issue. Are you animating anything else at the same time? Other animations might conflict

Comment: No. Nothing else is being animated.